# Should flags only be binary?

Tags: database, standards, naming

I may be erring towards pedantry here, but say I have a field in a database that currently has two values (but may contain more in future). I know I could name this as a flag (e.g. MY_FLAG) containing values 0 and 1, but should more values be required (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4), is it still correct to call the field a flag?

I seem to recall reading something previously, that a flag should always be binary, and anything else should be labelled more appropriately, but I may be mistaken. Does anyone know if my thinking is correct? If so, can you point me to any information on this please? My googling has turned nothing up!!

Thanks very much :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags are usually binary because when we say flag it means either it is **up(1) or down(0)**.
Just like it is used in military to flag up and down in order to show the war-signs. The concept of flagging is taken from there.

Regarding what you are saying

```
"your words : values be required (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4)"
```

In such a situation use **Enum**. **Enumerations** are build for such cases or sometimes what we do is , we justify the meaning of these numeric values in comments or in separate file so that more memory could be saved(we use tinyInt or bit field). But never name such a situation Flag.

Flags have standard meaning that is either **Up** or **Down**. It doesn't mean that you will get error or something but it is not a good practice. Hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'd already thought about enums, but thought MY_ENUM would may be a little ambiguous in the context I need to use it (won't go into detail). I'm not using _FLAG now, and am opting for something more relevant to the business rule it supports.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of conventions and the ability to maintain your database/code effectively. Technically, you can have a column called `my_flag` defined as a `varchar` and hold values like `"batman"` and `"barak obama"`.

By convention, flags are `boolean`. If you intend to have other values there, it's probably a better idea to call the column something else, like `some_enum`, or `my_code`.

Answer (score 0):

Very occasionally, people talk about (for example) tri-state flags, but Wikipedia and most of the dictionary definitions that I read reserve "flag" for binary / two state uses<sup>1</sup>.

Of course, neither Wikipedia or any dictionary has the *authority* to say some English usage is "incorrect".  "Correct" usage is really "conventional" usage; i.e. what other people say / write.

I would argue that saying or writing "tri-state flag" is unconventional, but it is unambiguous and serves its purpose of communicating a concept adequately.  (And the usage can be justified ...)

---

<sup>1 - Most, but not all; see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flag.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Don't call anything "flag". Or "count" or "mark" or "int" or "code". Name it like everything else in code: after what it means.

```
workday {mon..fri}
tall {yes,no}
zip_code {00000..99999}
state {AL..WY}
```

Notice that (something like) yes/no plays the 'flag' role of indicating a permanent dichotomy. (In lieu of boolean, which does that in the rest of the universe outside SQL). For when the specification/contract really is whether something is so. If a design might add more values you should use a different type.

Of course if you want to add more info to a name you can. Add distinctions that are meaningful if you can.

```
workday {monday..friday}
workday_abbrev {mon..fri}
is_tall {yes,no}
zip_plus_5 {00000-99..99999-99}
state_name {Alabama..Wyoming}
state_2 {AL..WY}
```